# FullCalendar Some Events (not all) on Wrong Dates

Tags: javascript, django, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am listing dates on FullCalendar and as you can see in the image, some dates show up correctly and some don't. I cannot find any reason that this is the case. The only thing the incorrect events have in common is that they have a start time of 8pm or later.

I selected the August 17th, which has two events. Only one shows correctly on the calendar.

Event data for the two events shown:

```
[2020-08-21 13:12:32,250] [INFO] [views : log_report] 20776 : 140579017103168 : {'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7fdb0e8f5518>, 'id': 140, 'created_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 12, 19, 59, 42, 969082, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'modified_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 17, 2, 33, 1, 101542, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'author_id': 324, 'session': '', 'event_type': 'lfp_event_paid', 'recipient_id': None, 'parent_hub_id': '3f42ec9e-8f42-4d0a-94ca-c4a6e98b01d6', 'event_title': 'Rise of the Runelords, a Pathfinder Adventure Path', 'unique_id': UUID('27268185-f906-49b0-b760-704bc2f9e3ef'), 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 17, 0, 15, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'end_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 17, 3, 15, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'budget_amount': 10, 'budget_details': 'No Budget Details', 'min_players': 2, 'max_players': 5, 'lfg_state': 'LFP', 'game_played_id': 27, 'other_game': '', 'session_type': 'One-Shot', 'location': 'Roll20 and Discord', 'location_link': 'https://app.roll20.net/campaigns/details/7386210/rise-of-the-runelords-anniversary-edition', 'req_status': 'inactive', 'paid_success': False, 'is_recurring': False, 'is_closed': False, 'is_full': False, 'is_private': False, 'is_paid': False, 'is_deleted': False}
[2020-08-21 13:12:32,249] [INFO] [views : log_report] 20776 : 140579017103168 : {'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7fdb0e8f5358>, 'id': 145, 'created_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 0, 51, 42, 543054, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'modified_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 17, 23, 2, 51, 389649, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'author_id': 324, 'session': '', 'event_type': 'lfp_event_free', 'recipient_id': None, 'parent_hub_id': 'a038e240-6a86-47b3-aa6c-5409edbb4362', 'event_title': 'Monday Night Age of Worms', 'unique_id': UUID('c4edb4c8-6fcd-4bb7-9c17-2be96c15f0bf'), 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 17, 23, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'end_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 18, 2, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'budget_amount': 0, 'budget_details': 'No Budget Details', 'min_players': 3, 'max_players': 4, 'lfg_state': 'LFP', 'game_played_id': 1, 'other_game': '', 'session_type': 'One-Shot', 'location': 'Foundry', 'location_link': 'http://71.179.132.53:30000', 'req_status': 'inactive', 'paid_success': False, 'is_recurring': False, 'is_closed': False, 'is_full': False, 'is_private': False, 'is_paid': False, 'is_deleted': False}
```

Here is my event code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    height: 560,
    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
    defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
    defaultDate: '{% now "Y-m-d" %}',

    eventRender: function(info) {
  $(info.el).tooltip({ 
    title: info.event.title,
    placement: "bottom",
    trigger: "hover",
    container: "body"
  });
},
    header: {
      left: 'title',
      center: '',
      right: 'prev, next'
    },

    events: [
      {% for event in connected_events %}
      {
        title: "{{event.event_title}}",
        start: "{{event.start_time|date:'c'}}",
        end: "{{event.end_time|date:'c'}}",
        url: "{% url 'events:event-detail' event.unique_id %}",
        details: "test",
        {%if event.budget_amount > 0 and event.lfg_state == 'LFGM' %}color : "#ff8f07"{%elif event.budget_amount <= 0 and event.lfg_state == 'LFGM' %}color : "#d943c5"{%elif event.budget_amount > 0 and event.lfg_state == 'LFP'%}color : "#1ad914"{%else%}color:"#38b3ff"{%endif%},
      },
      {% endfor %}
    ],
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

[image: One event correctly displayed on calendar while second event is on the wrong date.]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. However, since you didn't show us any of your actual event data, it's impossible to know what might be wrong. Since the data is highly relevant to the problem, please share it with us. The best way is probably to load your page, then go to View Source, find the `events:` definition and copy the generated JS data from there. If it's a big list you can always remove objects which aren't the focus of your issue and just reduce it to the examples you've shown in the picture. That will help to understand why the data is showing as it is on the calendar. Thanks

Comment: I've updated the original post with the event data of those two events displayed in the image, though this happens with some other events as well.

Comment: Thanks but one of the event data items you've shown doesn't match your picture - the Age of Worms one isn't shown. Can you double check it please? Also can you please provide it in the format I requested, from the source I requested? Then I can tell what fullCalendar is actually receiving, not what the object looks like while it's still on your server. (Although actually, both formats might be useful, as a comparison.)

Comment: Seems like the event data that you have posted has incorrect start and end time for the first event.

{'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 27, 21, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'end_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 16, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
{'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 17, 0, 15, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'end_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 17, 3, 15, tzinfo=<UTC>)}

The First event start time is 2020/08/27 and endtime is 2020/08/16. I think this is not an issue with the FullCalendar component. The issue has to be with the data. Verify the event data sent to fullcalendar.

Comment: Sorry I've been editing it - the events are correct now. I do see that one ends on 8/18. I will try to get the other data you requested.

Comment: Ok nvm I think I've spotted it. You realise that `2020-08-17 00:15` in UTC is `2020-08-16 20:15` in EST/EDT? Because EST is 4 hours behind UTC - so it's actually 8:15pm **the previous day**. See https://savvytime.com/converter/utc-to-est/12-15am . That's why Rise of the Runelords shows on the 16th. So the calendar is correct and the cards on the right-hand-side are wrong. (And your observation is about events after 8pm is entirely correct - now you know why!)

Comment: So how do those cards get populated, exactly? I'd guess in the code which populates card you are extracting the date portion from the UTC datetime and then showing it raw, without converting to EST. But presumably you managed to convert the time on the next line, since they show in EST. Whereas with fullCalendar you're feeding it the whole datetime as one entity, presumably with a UTC marker in the string (as per https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat ? I'm not a python user myself), so it converts the whole thing as one, to the correct EST date and time.

Comment: I'll check the front-end data and report back as soon as I can. It looks like it's converting the time correctly but not adjusting the date to match the change on the cards, so yes, the calendar is actually correct. It's odd that the datetime, being one model, does not auto-change the date as well if the time does correctly.

Comment: well it would depend how the code is written. e.g. If it simply extracts the date portion as a string from the UTC date and prints it, then it loses the timezone info and can't do a conversion. But presumably you need to make it use the same procedure as whatever it is using on the line where it prints the time, because that seems to be working ok.

Comment: You were right. Time was being converted correctly with {% timezone request.user.tz %} but the date was separated without the conversion applied. Unfortunately, I still have an issue where if I click 8/17 on the calendar, it shows both of the same events, but the cards do correctly show one on 8/16 and one on 8/17. It should of course only show the 8/17 event. I have already applied the timezone conversion into the JS as well but that did not change it.

Comment: Ok that's good progress. If you need help with what shows when you click on a day, you'd need to show us the code and data involved when the choice of what cards to display is made. Seems like maybe a similar issue with the date is going on somewhere, though. Or maybe a straight comparison of dates is being made, but the problem being that the date fullCalendar supplies is an EST one, whereas the date from the server maybe is the UTC one.

Comment: Alright, if you'd like to post an answer I'll accept it based on this question! Thanks again.

Comment: Done :-). Happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to realise that `2020-08-17 00:15` in UTC is `2020-08-16 20:15` in EST/EDT - because EST is 4 hours behind UTC - so it's actually 8:15pm the **previous day**. See https://savvytime.com/converter/utc-to-est/12-15am to convert between the timezones easily.

That's why `Rise of the Runelords` shows on the 16th in fullCalendar. So the calendar is correct and the cards on the right-hand-side are wrong. (And your observation is about events after 8pm is entirely correct - but now you know why!)

The relevant code isn't shown in the question, but you mentioned that upon investigation you discovered that the date shown in the cards was being loaded as a string without doing a timezone conversion (whereas the times were converted correctly, as was the whole datetime object passed to fullCalendar), and that once you sorted this out the date showed in the card correctly. A similar fix will also need to be applied to the code (also not visible) which decides which cards to display when a date is clicked in the calendar.